# Batch to exe Install adblock plus using batch file command

Tags: batch-file

> @echo off
>
> start firefox.exe "file:///%tmp%/tmp-ho2.xpi"

suddenly the files wont install
cause the path is not correct because bath to exe program create a new random name folder in temporary folder once you execute it.I cant configure out what folder name should i add in "file:///%tmp%/?????/tmp-ho2.xpi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start firefox.exe "%~p0\tmp-ho2.xpi"
```

`%~p0` is expanded to the directory where the batch program was run from.